# Docker-Toolbox storage on Windows

Tags: windows, docker

I'm quite new to Docker, and I realized for each build & run, nearly 15GB of my disk space disappeared.

I have used the following commands but they didn't help freeing up space:

```
$ docker system prune
$ docker container prune
$ docker image prune
$ docker volume prune
$ docker network prune
```

I then tried to check where my root directory is, which is: `/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker` but I have no idea where such directory is in Windows.

I also checked `C:\Users\<username>\.docker` directory, but there doesn't seem any files stored here.

There is also no Docker related folder under these directories as well , `C:\Users\Public\Documents` and `C:\ProgramData`

**Edit:** Using [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net/) tool, I found out that the file that takes too much space `is disk.vmdk` which is under `C:\Users\<username>\.docker\machine\machines\default`.

I tried to change its location to D: via updating default.vbox file under `C:\Users\<username>\.docker\machine\machines\default\default`, but it does not work.

Comment: I don't use Windows, but it should have some sort of Disk Usage utility, which will draw a pie chart of how your disk is being consumed. That will help you track down large files, including ones in Docker.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to delete the current docker environment and then setting it back again. However **this will destroy all your current images** :

1- delete the current docker environment :

```
docker-machine rm -f default
```

2- create a new docker environment:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-disk-size "80000" default
```

3- set then correct environment variables :

```
docker-machine env default
```

Hope it helps !

Credits goes to this articles which helped me figure it out : https://medium.com/@narven/docker-no-space-left-on-device-5c2276e4d61a

Answer (score 0):

`prune` commands without `--all` will only remove `dangling` resources. If you want to fully remove everything docker-related (volumes, network, containers, images) except for running containers and their respective images do:

`docker system prune --all`

Also, docker-toolbox runs inside a VM the folder you are looking for `/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker` is not in your windows machine but the linux VM.

Check [here](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/ssh/) how to SSH to that VM.